# KeyboardAwareScrollView - clicking on next TextInput hiding keyboard(React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, node-modules

I use `KeyboardAwareScrollView`. I want to keep keyboard open until button submitted. When I click on next `TextInput`, the keyboard is hiding(blur) and I must click again on next `TextInput` in order to focus on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on Android and I solve this by add `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always|handled'` to KeyboardAwareScrollView.